# Scrappy iteration over Scrappy selector

Tags: python, json, api, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape a website that uses an API that calls the HTML, so to do so I need to scrape the API and then scrape the HTML results from the API

I've used this post to manage to get the API response and get the HTML from it.

```
resp = json.loads(response.text)
selector= scrapy.Selector(text=resp['results'], type="html")
```

And it works fine, when I'm trying to get an attribute from the page I can use CSS or Xpath selectors and get the item

What I'm trying to do now is to iterate over the selector

```
        for item in selector:          
            title = job.css('a h2').extract()

            items ['title'] = title

            yield items
```

But when I'm applying this loop I'm getting TypeError

```
TypeError: 'Selector' object is not iterable
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is to iterate over this

```
<class 'scrapy.selector.unified.Selector'>
```

Or any other way to scrape the embedded HTML from the JSON API response

Update:
I'm able now to iterate over items, but now I cannot do the pagination

Comment: When you say `for item in resp:`, do you mean `for item in selector:`? Because `resp` does not appear to be the selector.

Comment: yes,  for item in selector. editing it now

Comment: What does the content of `resp['results']` look like? Maybe you need to iterate that content first, and then load each item from that into a `Selector`.

Answer (score 0):

use xpath extract to get the contents of the selector list

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping'
html=requests.get(url).content
sel=Selector(text=html)

for p in sel.xpath("//p"):
    print(p.xpath("text()").extract())
```